# LEFT JOIN sub-SELECT fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to select the the rows with the newest timestamp in `change_date` from a table in a `LEFT JOIN`. I really don't know why this query fails:

```
SELECT
    i.ID, i.title, i.create_date,
    u1.username creator_name,
    u2.username assignee
FROM item i
    LEFT JOIN user u1 ON u1.login_IDFK = i.creator_IDFK  
    LEFT JOIN user u2 ON u2.login_IDFK = i.assigned_to_IDFK
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(change_date), item_IDFK FROM item_state GROUP BY item_IDFK
    ) AS ist ON ist.item_IDFK = i.ID
```

I get the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS ist ON ist.item_IDFK = i.ID' at line 2 (Code: 1064)

Query works great without the last `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: what's the point of the last join anyways? you're not selecting and fields from it in the main field list, and there's no where clauses using it either.

Comment: Are you sure this is the query that gets the error (i.e., you haven't changed things when posting it)?

Comment: To re-emphasize Marc's comment, the additional `join` is a `left join`, so it is not filtering any rows.  The subquery with the `group by` is not increasing the number of rows, and no columns are being used.  The query is a no-op, but that is not reason to get this syntax error.

Comment: Ok corrected the MAX() thing cause I had that before. But this doesn't change things.

Comment: Next question.  Is this query being generated in an application?  Another possibility is that there is some unprintable character that MySQL catches, causing the problem.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER [can you add sql fiddle demo with your table definitions and sample dataset](http://sqlfiddle.com/) it would be easier to catch the error

Comment: Here is a simplified example although it's working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98157/2/0

Comment: One thing that would cause the problem is a comma or binary operator (`-`, `+`, `=`, etc) before the paren.  This would generate exactly the error you see.

Comment: I can't figure this out. it works in phpMyAdmin and the SQLFiddle but not inside the application with `PDO`. Also searched for non-printable chars there aren't any.

Comment: But it's still not actually doing anything !?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT change_date, item_IDFK FROM item_state GROUP BY item_IDFK)
```

You are using a group by clause without an aggregate. Each item in the select list must either be represented in the group by clause, or be part of an aggregate expression

I.E.

```
(Select Max(Change_Date), item_IDFK from item_state group by item_IDFK)
```

Comment: MySQL supports this using an extension to the language (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).  If this extension is turned off (by setting `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`), then I think the error message would be different.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Using something like `MAX()` or `MIN()` doesn't change the error message.

Answer (score 0):

try to save your last subquery in a view table, and after that, left join from that table, and see if the syntax error persists.

Comment: could you perhaps provide an example of this to make your answer clearer?

Comment: sure: the original query: 
select x, y, z from a left join (select x from y where clause) a_sub on a_sub.a = b.b. 
than you save your a_sub as a view:
create view as (select x from y where clause), than you make your original query like:
select x, y, z from a left join a_view on a_view.a = b.b. 
:-)